# Multiline Textfield with .Vertical axis going below keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview, textfield

I am having some issues with the textfield not moving up with the view.

I am using a textfield with Vertical axis (iOS 16) to create the multiline. This works correctly and stays above the keyboard as expected when it is not embedded in a scrollview. But as soon as the textfield is embedded in the scrollview the multiline just goes below the keyboard and you have to manually scroll to see the last line.

Please see code below. This should work correctly. But if you remove the scrollview you will notice the issue when typing.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Nam voluptatem necessitatibus aut quis odio rem error repudiandae id aliquam perferendis et quidem quaerat et enim harum! Cum nesciunt animi rem quia vero aut omnis eligendi in ducimus eaque sit mollitia fugit est animi nesciunt. Ut exercitationem nulla qui dolor nihil ad autem vero quo internos sapiente eum dicta nihil qui exercitationem cumque et consectetur dolore. Et fugiat officiis non harum voluptas et modi repellendus ut repellat dolorem 33 eveniet quidem qui galisum veritatis. Id consequatur tenetur et eaque voluptas in assumenda delectus et fuga praesentium rem provident delectus est necessitatibus sunt quo dignissimos dolorum. Et reiciendis error et rerum eligendi qui illum error? In soluta ipsum est molestiae pariatur hic voluptas animi qui cupiditate amet."
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            VStack() {
                TextField("Enter something", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If there are any GitHub repos you know that would also be great.

**Update:**
I have found a solution and will be posting it in the coming days.

Comment: Does it work correctly with or without the ScrollView?

Comment: @mahan it works correctly without scrollview

Comment: Just curious why do you need a scroll view? Why not use it without it?

Comment: @user1046037 because in the main version of my app, there are multiple views + text fields and as the view grows some items are obviously off the screen and I need to be able to scroll to them…  if there is a way to do it without that would be great… if that doesn’t make sense maybe I can upload a screenshot to show you what I mean?

Comment: I don't know how to solve your issue, the only design choice I can think of is have a Text (of line limit 4) and tapping on it can go to the detail view (using navigation link) in that detail view have only the `TextField`.

Comment: @user1046037 interesting idea, I appreciate it. I will think about it.

Comment: Did you post a solution anywhere? Running into the same problem

Comment: Able to post what you came up with?  I am running into this as well, took a while for me to realize the vertical axis setting was breaking the avoid-keyboard-scrolling

Comment: @Charles could you post your solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a definitive answer. In the simulator some buggy behavior appears. Try this out and see on a real device (that I don't have here).

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Nam voluptatem necessitatibus aut quis odio rem error repudiandae id aliquam perferendis et quidem quaerat et enim harum! Cum nesciunt animi rem quia vero aut omnis eligendi in ducimus eaque sit mollitia fugit est animi nesciunt. Ut exercitationem nulla qui dolor nihil ad autem vero quo internos sapiente eum dicta nihil qui exercitationem cumque et consectetur dolore. Et fugiat officiis non harum voluptas et modi repellendus ut repellat dolorem 33 eveniet quidem qui galisum veritatis. Id consequatur tenetur et eaque voluptas in assumenda delectus et fuga praesentium rem provident delectus est necessitatibus sunt quo dignissimos dolorum. Et reiciendis error et rerum eligendi qui illum error? In soluta ipsum est molestiae pariatur hic voluptas animi qui cupiditate amet."
    
    @Namespace var bottomText
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                Text("Title")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                TextField("Enter something", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .onChange(of: text) { newValue in
                        print("Fired.")
                        withAnimation {
                            proxy.scrollTo(bottomText, anchor: .center)
                        }
                    }
                Color.red.frame(height: 50).id(bottomText)
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is, if the text comes from a viewModel via @Published I could sink on it using `.onReceive` then call `proxy.scrollTo` on the MainQueue. Also try to attach the ID directly on the TextField... now we also have `TextEditor` see if this is a better option for you. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Allan, I really appreciate your answer thank you! I have had a quick look with the example code above and it is better than anything I have come up with so far, but it does have strange feel/buggy.. I will try and implement the idea on my main app, and see if it is any better. I have been thinking a text editor is a better option, but I did give it a quick go and it seems there is the same problem... I do not understand why this is so difficult!! Have you any examples of this with a textEditor? if so It might be the best option.

Comment: So I tried it in my main app, and similar issue as the test code... It is quite jumpy, but what the main issue is: The textField is at the top of the screen so you have roughly 300-400 points between the top of the keyboard and bottom of textfield

Comment: Unfortunately we still have some "ghost" behaviors in SwiftUI... inexplicable.

Comment: Yep, just spent a few hours going round in circles with it again... I can't get it to work with a textEditor at all either, just don't understand why apple is like this! It's quite an important part of my app haha! Thanks for your help anyway, if you think of something else I'd greatly appreciate it.. I will update here once I find a solution, not giving up just yet!

Comment: I tried a bit with `@FocusState` to detect when keyboard is up but not sure how to get cursor position. (so couldn't scroll to cursor position). It scrolls to end / center / top but I feel bespoke solution might catch you off guard better solve it using a different UI design.

Comment: @AllanGarcia `ScrollViewReader` should be inside `ScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

When TextField axis is .vertical, anchor must be .top

```swift
VStack {
   // ... other code

   .onSubmit {
       // update state here !!
       if (i + 1) < inputsValues.count {
           focusedInput = i + 1
       } else {
           focusedInput = nil
       }
   }
}
.onChange(of: focusedInput) {
  // When TextField axis is .vertical, anchor must be .top
  proxy.scrollTo($0, anchor: .top)
}
```

Here is full [source code](https://gist.github.com/gewill/7f81742fc4e1f7ae23b2f4ffc0fee300).

Comment: Hi Will, thanks for the answer. However, your code is good for going to the next textfield but does not fix my issue mentioned above. Basically, I am looking for a way to have a Multiline Textfield with a .vertical axis embedded in a scrollview to expand and stay above the keyboard. (the issue I am having is being caused by the scrollview.)